# equation of the tangent to the curve for equation and x value

Tags: calculus

I am asked to find the equation of the tangent to the curve given:

${y = 3x - x^3}$ at ${x = 1}$

So I would say:

${{dy\over dx} = 3 - 3x^2}$

at x = 1

gradient = ${3 - 3(1)^2} = 0$

If I use ${y = 0(x - 1)}$

which would make ${y = 0}$

but the answer in the text book is y = 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find the y-coordinate first thats the mistake. By plugging in  $x=1$ in given eqso its $3-1=2$ so now you have gradient $m=0$ now plug all this in $(y-y_1)=m(x-x_1)$ you get $(y-2)=0(x-1)$ thus equation is $y=2$ hope it clear

Answer (score 0):

One mistake where you find the value of y. I don't understand how you came to the point that y=0(x-1). Note that the value of y on the tangent i the point of x=1 is the same as the value of y on the curve when x=1, since that is the place you want to find a tangent for.